# The City value in dxAutoComplete in a form takes time to appear when you edit the form Devextreme

Tags: javascript, html, forms, devextreme

I have a form using DevExtreme where the user input city name in addresses. The city is based on dxAutoComplete. However, when I want to edit the address form, the city value takes some time to appear.
I don't know what is the cause for this, and how to solve it. Do you have to modify when you load the dataSource or when you add the data field?

Here is a snippet on the city DataField.

```js
    {
        dataField: "CITY",
        label: {text: "City"},
        editorType: "dxAutocomplete",  
        editorOptions: {
            dataSource:  CitiesCS,
            placeholder: "Type a city name...",
            valueExpr: "NAME_ASCII",                                                    
            searchExpr: ["NAME", "NAME_ASCII"],
            itemTemplate: function(data) {
                return $("<div>" + data.CITY_DISPLAY  + "</div>");
            }, 
            //showClearButton: true,                                                  
        }
    }
```